# Center text responsively

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The text "**Autenticação**" is not getting completely centered. I thought about using `margin-right` (this solution works only on the resolution of my machine). I wonder if anyone can help me, follow code:

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.logos-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
    padding: 12px 8rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #001C44;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cdd1d3;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.logos-container img {
    height: 3rem;
}
.logos-container h2 {
    flex: 1;
}
.loginContainer{
    background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NnfNFJ1/fatura.png") no-repeat left 20px;
    background-size: 24%;
    height: calc(100vh - 5.25rem);
}
.footer {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.footer a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="logos-container">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/njPs6xJ/min.png" class="logomin" alt="Ministerio da Educação" />
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mcKb85g/aetr.png" class="logoaetr" alt="Agrupamento de Escolas Tomaz Ribeiro" />
        <h2>Autenticação</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="loginContainer">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="https://google.pt/">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a> <span>Versão: 1.0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change one parameter in `.logos-container`: `justify-content` must be set to `center`

(BTW: Actually the `h2` *is*  centered, it's the images above it which were not centered...)

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.logos-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 12px 8rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #001C44;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cdd1d3;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.logos-container img {
    height: 3rem;
}
.logos-container h2 {
    flex: 1;
}
.loginContainer{
    background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NnfNFJ1/fatura.png") no-repeat left 20px;
    background-size: 24%;
    height: calc(100vh - 5.25rem);
}
.footer {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
.footer a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="logos-container">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/njPs6xJ/min.png" class="logomin" alt="Ministerio da Educação" />
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mcKb85g/aetr.png" class="logoaetr" alt="Agrupamento de Escolas Tomaz Ribeiro" />
        <h2>Autenticação</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="loginContainer">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="https://google.pt/">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a> <span>Versão: 1.0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but it aligns with the beginning of the text, that is, the middle is the beginning of the text, you can leave the middle in the center of the text?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean (?)

Comment: Are you sure your comment refers to *my*  answer (not maybe the other one?)

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I updated the page I accepted the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You could `position` the `h2` as `absolute` and also set its `right` and `left` `margin`s as `auto` and its `right` and `left` values as 0:

```
.logos-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```

Be careful because when resizing the browser it will overlap with the other children elements.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kdw7vcfy/3/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logos-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  padding: 12px 8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #001C44;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cdd1d3;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.logos-container img {
  height: 3rem;
}

.logos-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.loginContainer {
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/NnfNFJ1/fatura.png") no-repeat left 20px;
  background-size: 24%;
  height: calc(100vh - 5.25rem);
}

.footer {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #9B9B9B;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="logos-container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/njPs6xJ/min.png" class="logomin" alt="Ministerio da Educação" />
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/mcKb85g/aetr.png" class="logoaetr" alt="Agrupamento de Escolas Tomaz Ribeiro" />
    <h2>Autenticação</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="loginContainer">
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <a href="https://google.pt/">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a> <span>Versão: 1.0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```